# How to load a PGM image with correct color range in Java?

Tags: java, image, load, pgm

I'm doing a work in which I have to load a PGM image in Java programming language.

I have no problems in loading it from a file, since I'm using Apache Sanselan framework and it's too easy to do:

```
BufferedImage image = Sanselan.getBufferedImage(new File("image.pgm"));
```

However, when I try to draw it on a Swing Canvas, I realise that the color range is not correctly recognised. The problem is that the maximum color value loaded is always 255 (while, in the PGM file, another maximum color can be specified).

For example, when loading the PGM image

```
P2
# Shows the word "FEEP" (example from Netpbm main page on PGM)
24 8
15
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  3  3  3  3  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0 15  0
0  3  3  3  0  0  0  7  7  7  0  0  0 11 11 11  0  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 14 13 12 11 10 9  8  7
```

which maximum color is 15, I get a whole black image because the maximum color is taken as 255 (so a pixel with value 15, that would have been white if the image was correctly loaded, is almost black in this case).

I tried using Java Advanced Image I/O Tools but I got exactly the same problem.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Thanks!